# B-1 visa application and SSN from F-1 visa validity

Tags: visas, usa, paperwork

I am going to the US on a B-1 visa to attend a conference. On the DS-160 form, it is asking for a US SSN (Social Security Number) and TIN (Taxpayer Identification Number).

Previously, I was an international student who graduated and did my OPT (Optional Practical Training) for one year. I was given an SSN for that work authorization.

Will this SSN still be valid or should I leave that as "not applicable" because it was tied to that OPT?

Answer (score 5):

Your SSN remains valid and you should enter the same one - they probably just use it to cross-check your history.

In fact, there are [only a few circumstances](https://faq.ssa.gov/link/portal/34011/34019/Article/3789/Can-I-change-my-Social-Security-number) in which you can apply to get a new number if you already have one.